# Error "xrange is invalid" when trying to plot an histogram with Gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, histogram

I want to plot an histogram with Gnuplot and I have the following code:

```
n=100 #number of intervals
max=31 #max value
min=22  #min value
width=(max-min)/n #interval width
#function used to map a value to the intervals
hist(x,width)=width*floor(x/width)+width/2.0

GNUTERM = "x11"
set terminal postscript enhanced color
set output "histo.ps"
plot "file_log" u (hist($1,width)):(1.0) smooth freq w boxes lc rgb "blue" notitle
```

Usually this code was working fine, but right now I'm getting a

```
"histo.gnu", line 48: warning: Skipping data file with no valid points

plot "file_log" u (hist($1,width)):(1.0) smooth freq w boxes lc rgb "blue" notitle 
                                                                                       ^
"histo.gnu", line 48: x range is invalid
```

I really don't understand why, because the values in the file are indeed between 22 and 31...Any idea?

Comment: The erroneous line doesn't seem to be line 48. Do you have some more code which you are not showing? Does it maybe help if you add a `reset` or `reset session` at the beginning?

Comment: Yes, but I think that theses lines are not relevant...The line 48 corresponds to the line that starts with "Plot". I tried `reset` but it does not change, and `reset session` is giving me `"histo.gnu", line 13: warning: expected optional axis name
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is this line

```
width=(max-min)/n #interval width
```

Since max,min, and n are all integers gnuplot uses integer arithmetic, so 11/100 = 0.   You could fix it by saying `width=real(max-min)/n` or else make sure the limiting values are real numbers:

```
n=100 #number of intervals
max=31.0 #max value
min=22.0  #min value
width=(max-min)/n #interval width
```